# redirect logout to phtml page instead of logging out

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, url, xml, logout

Log out option will be there in entire site and if we click on "LOg out".

it will log out the customer from the site.

but for some reason, if i click on log out , it should redirect to some link.

for example, in some pages if we click on log out, i want to redirect to some phtml page link

**Update**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Customer
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Customer Data Helper
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Customer
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Customer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Query param name for last url visited
     */
    const REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME = 'referer';

    /**
     * Route for customer account login page
     */
    const ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN = 'customer/account/login';

    /**
     * Config name for Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in setting
     */
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD = 'customer/startup/redirect_dashboard';

    /**
     * Config paths to VAT related customer groups
     */
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_INTRA_UNION_GROUP = 'customer/create_account/viv_intra_union_group';
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_DOMESTIC_GROUP = 'customer/create_account/viv_domestic_group';
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_INVALID_GROUP = 'customer/create_account/viv_invalid_group';
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_ERROR_GROUP = 'customer/create_account/viv_error_group';

    /**
     * Config path to option that enables/disables automatic group assignment based on VAT
     */
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_GROUP_AUTO_ASSIGN = 'customer/create_account/viv_disable_auto_group_assign_default';

    /**
     * Config path to support email
     */
    const XML_PATH_SUPPORT_EMAIL = 'trans_email/ident_support/email';

    /**
     * WSDL of VAT validation service
     *
     */
    const VAT_VALIDATION_WSDL_URL = 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl';

    /**
     * Configuration path to expiration period of reset password link
     */
    const XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_RESET_PASSWORD_LINK_EXPIRATION_PERIOD
        = 'default/customer/password/reset_link_expiration_period';

    /**
     * VAT class constants
     */
    const VAT_CLASS_DOMESTIC    = 'domestic';
    const VAT_CLASS_INTRA_UNION = 'intra_union';
    const VAT_CLASS_INVALID     = 'invalid';
    const VAT_CLASS_ERROR       = 'error';

    /**
     * Customer groups collection
     *
     * @var Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Group_Collection
     */
    protected $_groups;

    /**
     * Check customer is logged in
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve logged in customer
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        if (empty($this->_customer)) {
            $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        }
        return $this->_customer;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer groups collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Group_Collection
     */
    public function getGroups()
    {
        if (empty($this->_groups)) {
            $this->_groups = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getResourceCollection()
                ->setRealGroupsFilter()
                ->load();
        }
        return $this->_groups;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current (logged in) customer object
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
     */
    public function getCurrentCustomer()
    {
        return $this->getCustomer();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current customer name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->getCustomer()->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Check customer has address
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function customerHasAddresses()
    {
        return count($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses()) > 0;
    }

    /**************************************************************************
     * Customer urls
     */

    /**
     * Retrieve customer login url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl(self::ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN, $this->getLoginUrlParams());
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve parameters of customer login url
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLoginUrlParams()
    {
        $params = array();

        $referer = $this->_getRequest()->getParam(self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);

        if (!$referer && !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD)
            && !Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getNoReferer()
        ) {
            $referer = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true));
            $referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($referer);
        }

        if ($referer) {
            $params = array(self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME => $referer);
        }

        return $params;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer login POST URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLoginPostUrl()
    {
        $params = array();
        if ($this->_getRequest()->getParam(self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)) {
            $params = array(
                self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME => $this->_getRequest()->getParam(self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)
            );
        }
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/loginPost', $params);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer logout url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogoutUrl()
    {
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if (strpos($currentUrl,'marketplaceaccount/myproductslist ') !== false) {
   return $this->_getUrl('marketplace');
   }else 
   {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/logout');
     }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer dashboard url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDashboardUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer account page url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccountUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer register form url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRegisterUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/create');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer register form post url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRegisterPostUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/createpost');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer account edit form url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEditUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/edit');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer edit POST URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEditPostUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/editpost');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve url of forgot password page
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getForgotPasswordUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
    }

    /**
     * Check is confirmation required
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isConfirmationRequired()
    {
        return $this->getCustomer()->isConfirmationRequired();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve confirmation URL for Email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailConfirmationUrl($email = null)
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/confirmation', array('email' => $email));
    }

    /**
     * Check whether customers registration is allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isRegistrationAllowed()
    {
        $result = new Varien_Object(array('is_allowed' => true));
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_registration_is_allowed', array('result' => $result));
        return $result->getIsAllowed();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve name prefix dropdown options
     *
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function getNamePrefixOptions($store = null)
    {
        return $this->_prepareNamePrefixSuffixOptions(
            Mage::helper('customer/address')->getConfig('prefix_options', $store)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve name suffix dropdown options
     *
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function getNameSuffixOptions($store = null)
    {
        return $this->_prepareNamePrefixSuffixOptions(
            Mage::helper('customer/address')->getConfig('suffix_options', $store)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Unserialize and clear name prefix or suffix options
     *
     * @param string $options
     * @return array|bool
     */
    protected function _prepareNamePrefixSuffixOptions($options)
    {
        $options = trim($options);
        if (empty($options)) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = array();
        $options = explode(';', $options);
        foreach ($options as $value) {
            $value = $this->escapeHtml(trim($value));
            $result[$value] = $value;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Generate unique token for reset password confirmation link
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateResetPasswordLinkToken()
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer reset password link expiration period in days
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getResetPasswordLinkExpirationPeriod()
    {
        return (int) Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_RESET_PASSWORD_LINK_EXPIRATION_PERIOD);
    }

    /**
     * Get default customer group id
     *
     * @param Mage_Core_Model_Store|string|int $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDefaultCustomerGroupId($store = null)
    {
        return (int)Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_ID, $store);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer group ID based on his VAT number
     *
     * @param string $customerCountryCode
     * @param Varien_Object $vatValidationResult
     * @param Mage_Core_Model_Store|string|int $store
     * @return null|int
     */
    public function getCustomerGroupIdBasedOnVatNumber($customerCountryCode, $vatValidationResult, $store = null)
    {
        $groupId = null;

        $vatClass = $this->getCustomerVatClass($customerCountryCode, $vatValidationResult, $store);

        $vatClassToGroupXmlPathMap = array(
            self::VAT_CLASS_DOMESTIC => self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_DOMESTIC_GROUP,
            self::VAT_CLASS_INTRA_UNION => self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_INTRA_UNION_GROUP,
            self::VAT_CLASS_INVALID => self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_INVALID_GROUP,
            self::VAT_CLASS_ERROR => self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_ERROR_GROUP
        );

        if (isset($vatClassToGroupXmlPathMap[$vatClass])) {
            $groupId = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig($vatClassToGroupXmlPathMap[$vatClass], $store);
        }

        return $groupId;
    }

    /**
     * Send request to VAT validation service and return validation result
     *
     * @param string $countryCode
     * @param string $vatNumber
     * @param string $requesterCountryCode
     * @param string $requesterVatNumber
     *
     * @return Varien_Object
     */
    public function checkVatNumber($countryCode, $vatNumber, $requesterCountryCode = '', $requesterVatNumber = '')
    {
        // Default response
        $gatewayResponse = new Varien_Object(array(
            'is_valid' => false,
            'request_date' => '',
            'request_identifier' => '',
            'request_success' => false
        ));

        if (!extension_loaded('soap')) {
            Mage::logException(Mage::exception('Mage_Core',
                Mage::helper('core')->__('PHP SOAP extension is required.')));
            return $gatewayResponse;
        }

        if (!$this->canCheckVatNumber($countryCode, $vatNumber, $requesterCountryCode, $requesterVatNumber)) {
            return $gatewayResponse;
        }

        try {
            $soapClient = $this->_createVatNumberValidationSoapClient();

            $requestParams = array();
            $requestParams['countryCode'] = $countryCode;
            $requestParams['vatNumber'] = str_replace(array(' ', '-'), array('', ''), $vatNumber);
            $requestParams['requesterCountryCode'] = $requesterCountryCode;
            $requestParams['requesterVatNumber'] = str_replace(array(' ', '-'), array('', ''), $requesterVatNumber);

            // Send request to service
            $result = $soapClient->checkVatApprox($requestParams);

            $gatewayResponse->setIsValid((boolean) $result->valid);
            $gatewayResponse->setRequestDate((string) $result->requestDate);
            $gatewayResponse->setRequestIdentifier((string) $result->requestIdentifier);
            $gatewayResponse->setRequestSuccess(true);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $gatewayResponse->setIsValid(false);
            $gatewayResponse->setRequestDate('');
            $gatewayResponse->setRequestIdentifier('');
        }

        return $gatewayResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Check if parameters are valid to send to VAT validation service
     *
     * @param string $countryCode
     * @param string $vatNumber
     * @param string $requesterCountryCode
     * @param string $requesterVatNumber
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canCheckVatNumber($countryCode, $vatNumber, $requesterCountryCode, $requesterVatNumber)
    {
        $result = true;
        /** @var $coreHelper Mage_Core_Helper_Data */
        $coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');

        if (!is_string($countryCode)
            || !is_string($vatNumber)
            || !is_string($requesterCountryCode)
            || !is_string($requesterVatNumber)
            || empty($countryCode)
            || !$coreHelper->isCountryInEU($countryCode)
            || empty($vatNumber)
            || (empty($requesterCountryCode) && !empty($requesterVatNumber))
            || (!empty($requesterCountryCode) && empty($requesterVatNumber))
            || (!empty($requesterCountryCode) && !$coreHelper->isCountryInEU($requesterCountryCode))
        ) {
            $result = false;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get VAT class
     *
     * @param string $customerCountryCode
     * @param Varien_Object $vatValidationResult
     * @param Mage_Core_Model_Store|string|int|null $store
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getCustomerVatClass($customerCountryCode, $vatValidationResult, $store = null)
    {
        $vatClass = null;

        $isVatNumberValid = $vatValidationResult->getIsValid();

        if (is_string($customerCountryCode)
            && !empty($customerCountryCode)
            && $customerCountryCode === Mage::helper('core')->getMerchantCountryCode($store)
            && $isVatNumberValid
        ) {
            $vatClass = self::VAT_CLASS_DOMESTIC;
        } elseif ($isVatNumberValid) {
            $vatClass = self::VAT_CLASS_INTRA_UNION;
        } else {
            $vatClass = self::VAT_CLASS_INVALID;
        }

        if (!$vatValidationResult->getRequestSuccess()) {
            $vatClass = self::VAT_CLASS_ERROR;
        }

        return $vatClass;
    }

    /**
     * Get validation message that will be displayed to user by VAT validation result object
     *
     * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Address $customerAddress
     * @param bool $customerGroupAutoAssignDisabled
     * @param Varien_Object $validationResult
     * @return Varien_Object
     */
    public function getVatValidationUserMessage($customerAddress, $customerGroupAutoAssignDisabled, $validationResult)
    {
        $message = '';
        $isError = true;
        $customerVatClass = $this->getCustomerVatClass($customerAddress->getCountryId(), $validationResult);
        $groupAutoAssignDisabled = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_VIV_GROUP_AUTO_ASSIGN);

        $willChargeTaxMessage    = $this->__('You will be charged tax.');
        $willNotChargeTaxMessage = $this->__('You will not be charged tax.');

        if ($validationResult->getIsValid()) {
            $message = $this->__('Your VAT ID was successfully validated.');
            $isError = false;

            if (!$groupAutoAssignDisabled && !$customerGroupAutoAssignDisabled) {
                $message .= ' ' . ($customerVatClass == self::VAT_CLASS_DOMESTIC
                    ? $willChargeTaxMessage
                    : $willNotChargeTaxMessage);
            }
        } else if ($validationResult->getRequestSuccess()) {
            $message = sprintf(
                $this->__('The VAT ID entered (%s) is not a valid VAT ID.') . ' ',
                $this->escapeHtml($customerAddress->getVatId())
            );
            if (!$groupAutoAssignDisabled && !$customerGroupAutoAssignDisabled) {
                $message .= $willChargeTaxMessage;
            }
        }
        else {
            $contactUsMessage = sprintf($this->__('If you believe this is an error, please contact us at %s'),
                Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUPPORT_EMAIL));

            $message = $this->__('Your Tax ID cannot be validated.') . ' '
                . (!$groupAutoAssignDisabled && !$customerGroupAutoAssignDisabled
                    ? $willChargeTaxMessage . ' ' : '')
                . $contactUsMessage;
        }

        $validationMessageEnvelope = new Varien_Object();
        $validationMessageEnvelope->setMessage($message);
        $validationMessageEnvelope->setIsError($isError);

        return $validationMessageEnvelope;
    }

    /**
     * Create SOAP client based on VAT validation service WSDL
     *
     * @param boolean $trace
     * @return SoapClient
     */
    protected function _createVatNumberValidationSoapClient($trace = false)
    {
        return new SoapClient(self::VAT_VALIDATION_WSDL_URL, array('trace' => $trace));
    }
}
```

Comment: Then when  a customer will logout from it panel

Comment: @AmitBera thanks for replying form y posts.... ya, we made something like this page : https://seller.flipkart.com/ so that when customer log out , we will redirect to this kind of page. so in that page we gave option for customer to login.....

Comment: you have already got answer.. :

Comment: ya buddy, why you are asking like this ?

Comment: before your reply... your  have accept the satti :)

Comment: ya, i swapped the code gave by Qaisar Satti.... you also not helping me now a days:-).... he is helping me lot....

Comment: ha ha : i am too busy on few project from last 2 month:.. so  i  have not reply you

Comment: that's fine... i knew that... before you woke up morning 5 o clock and help others here.... hope your project will complete soon....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php` copy this file to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
```

change this function as you want line `226`.

```
public function getLogoutUrl()
    {
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if (strpos($currentUrl,'marketplaceaccount') !== false) {
   return $this->_getUrl('marketplace');
   }else 
   {
        return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/logout');
     }
    }
```

Comment: is it works for particular pages or in whole site ?

Comment: i thing whole website

Comment: it will work for whole website. but you can put your  check for specific page.

Comment: i am in this page now : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/ here if i click on log out , i want to redirect to this page :" http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/ ". what i have to do now ?

Comment: added ur code as required

Comment: please check updated question, i added as you said, but its not working.....

Comment: i swapped the urls in your answer, it worked.....

Comment: suppose if i want in this page also means :http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/ , please give updated code, like this lot of pages are there.

Comment: add marketplaceaccount in condition and update the answer kindly check

Comment: i used both codes, that one you gave before and now . but its displaying like error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getLogoutUrl()

Comment: add only one function add new code only ...

Comment: please update the code for these 2 pages.

marketplaceaccount/myproductslist

marketplaceaccount

Comment: ` marketplaceaccount` this will work for all page that contain  `marketplaceaccount` remove previous and add this

Comment: i swapped the code, now its working for both links.....

Comment: now you find solution for login url?